# JavaScript Error -- TypeError: a <function> is undefined

Tags: jquery, es6-promise

I have this sequential code inside a `startIndex()` function, executing `hidePace()` before `showFullMenu()`:

```
function startIndex(){
    hidePace().done(
            showFullMenu()
            );
}
```

This works properly, applying `hidePace()` actions before `showFullMenu()` actions, but when actions contained on hidePace are finished, Firefox console brings an error: `TypeError: hidePace(...) is undefined`

Even though this works properly, I'd like to know the reason for this error, as `hidePace()` exists, and works.

FUNCTIONS:

```
function hidePace(){
   $height = $(window).height(); 

   setTimeout(function(){    
      $('.pace-progress,.velo2').animate({'opacity': 0,queue: false},0);
      $('.logoL,.logoLback').animate({'top': '-'+$height,'opacity':0,queue: false},3000); 
   },500);

   setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('.velo').animate({'opacity': 0},1000);      
   },700);  

   setTimeout(function(){
     $('.menuOff').animate({'width': $height-260,queue: false});
     $('.logoL,.logoLback,.velo,.velo2').remove();
  },3000);   
}

function showFullMenu(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(mobileView===0){ 
        $('.textc').animate({'width': 148,queue: false}, 1200,"easeInQuart");
      }},1500);   

   setTimeout(function(){
     if(mobileView===0){ 
        $('.textc,.menu').css('border', 'none').animate({'height': $height-210,queue: false}, 1000,"easeInQuart", function(){
             $('.sub1').css('top',$('.multilevel[data-id=1]').offset().top);
             $('.sub2').css('top',$('.multilevel[data-id=2]').offset().top);
             $('.sub3').css('top',$('.multilevel[data-id=3]').offset().top);
        });     
    }

     $('.menuOff').animate({'width': $height-260,queue: false});
},3000);
}


function startIndex(){
    hidePace().done(
            showFullMenu()
            );
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
      <div class="logoLback"></div>
      <div class="logoL"></div>      
      <div class="velo"></div>
      <div class="velo2"></div>


      <div class="logoBar"><img src="img/mobilemenu1.jpg" alt="menu" class="mobileMenu"/><img class="logo2" src="img/LOGO2.jpg" alt="logo"></div>

      <div class="bk8"></div>
      <div class="bg" data-ibg-bg="img/slides/04.jpg">
      <div class="pattern"></div>

      <header>

      <div class="logo"></div>  

      <div class="touchTextc"></div> 
        <ul class="touchMenu">
           <li class="" data-id="17">1</li>
           <li class="" data-id="1">2<span>+</span></li>
           <li class="" data-id="2">3<span>+</span></li>
           <li class="" data-id="3">4<span>+</span></li>
           <li class="" data-id="19">5</li>
           <li class="" data-id="99">6</li>
           <li class="" data-id="03">7</li>
           <li class="" data-id="02">8</li>
           <li class="" data-id="07">9</li>
        </ul>


      <div class="textc"></div>      
        <ul class="menu">
           <li class="multilevel lightMe" data-id="1">Cocinas<span>+</span></li>
           <li class="multilevel lightMe" data-id="2">2<span>+</span></li>
           <li class="multilevel lightMe" data-id="3">3<span>+</span></li>
           <li class="lightMe executeGallery dynamicBack"  data-back="25" data-href="demo.html">4</li>
           <li class="lightMe executePanel dynamicBack" data-back="26" data-href="demo.html">5</li>
           <li class="lightMe executePanel dynamicBack blog" data-back="99" data-href="demo.html">6<img class="popup" src="img/popup.png" alt=""/> </li>
           <li class="lightMe executePanel dynamicBack" data-back="98" data-href="demo.html">7</li>
           <li class="lightMe executePanel dynamicBack" data-back="96" data-href="demo.html">8</li>
           <li class="lightMe executePanel dynamicBack" data-back="97" data-href="demo.html">9</li>
        </ul>



      <ul class="submenu sub1" data-id="1">
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="06"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">1</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="07"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">2</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="03"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">3</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="01"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">4</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="02"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">5</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="05"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">6</a></li>    
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="18"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">7</a></li>    
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="19"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="cocinas-.html">8</a></li>    
      </ul>



      <ul class="submenu sub3" data-id="3">
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="12"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="1.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="13"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="2.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="14"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="3.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="15"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="4.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="16"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="5.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="17"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="6.html">demo</a></li>
      </ul>  

      <ul class="submenu sub2" data-id="2">
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="08"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="2.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="09"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="3.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="10"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="4.html">demo</a></li>
         <li class="lightMe"><a href="#" data-back="11"  class="dynamicBack" data-href="5.html">demo</a></li>
      </ul>



      </header>
      <div id="content2"></div>
      <div class='backsC'></div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
              $(".bg").interactive_bg();
         </script>
      </div>




      <script>
          Pace.on("done", function(){
             startIndex(); 
          });

        </script>

   </body>
```

Comment: what is the value returned by `hidePace`

Comment: There's no returning value, that function has only animations. Is this what you meant? I'll update the code with full functions.

Comment: then that is the problem.. for `don` o work that function need to return a promise object

Comment: Hi @Andreas, .done is not ment to wait until first function finishes and trigger second one? I was wrong then

Comment: when do you want `showFullMenu` to execute? do you want that to execute after all the naimations in `hidePace` is finished

Comment: yes. after hidePace finishes

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: @Biomehanika Please post the html as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note, appear syntax error at `options` of `.animate()` , where `options` , if provided , should be in separate object than animated properties .

---

At `js` at Question , no jQuery promise appear returned from `hidePace` for `.done()` to be chained to.

Try utilizing `delay()` , `.promise()` , `$.when()`

```
function hidePace() {
  $height = $(window).height();
  var a = function() {
    $('.pace-progress,.velo2').delay(500).animate({
      opacity: 0},{
      queue: false,
      duration:0
    });
    return $('.logoL,.logoLback').animate({
      top: '-' + $height,
      opacity:0 },{
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
    }).promise("fx")
};

var b = function() {
  return $('.velo').delay(700).animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 1000).promise("fx")
};


var c = function() {
  return $('.menuOff').delay(3000).animate({
    width: $height - 260
  }, {
    queue: false,
    done: function() {
      $('.logoL,.logoLback,.velo,.velo2').remove();
    }
  }).promise("fx")
};

return $.when(a(), b(), c())
}

function showFullMenu() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (mobileView === 0) {
      $('.textc').animate({
        width: 148},{
        queue: false,
        duration:1200, 
        easing:"easeInQuart"
      });
    }
  }, 1500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (mobileView === 0) {
      $('.textc,.menu').css('border', 'none').animate({
        height: $height - 210},{
        queue: false,
        duration: 1000,
        easing:"easeInQuart", 
        done: function() {
        $('.sub1').css('top', $('.multilevel[data-id=1]').offset().top);
        $('.sub2').css('top', $('.multilevel[data-id=2]').offset().top);
        $('.sub3').css('top', $('.multilevel[data-id=3]').offset().top);
      }});
    }

    $('.menuOff').animate({
      'width': $height - 260},{
      queue: false
    });
  }, 3000);
}


function startIndex() {
  hidePace().done(showFullMenu);
}
```

Comment: I have inserted an alert into "a" and it does not emerge, actions contained on var a = function()... do not apply. function "b" works properly. On the other hand, is not there a mistake on the "a" function opacity? (...'opacity': },{...)

Comment: @Biomehanika _"On the other hand, is not there a mistake on the "a" function opacity? (...'opacity': },{...)"_ Yes , see updated post